# Flash multi-touch on Windows 7 - configurable?

Tags: flash, zooming, mousewheel, multi-touch

I'm testing a Flash application in Windows 7 that uses the mouse wheel to perform a zoom.  When I do a standard pinch gesture the app properly zooms in or out, so I'm guessing that somewhere the gesture is getting converted to mouse wheels.  The only problem is that the zooming is really slow - is there a way to configure this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody (Flash or W7) is smart enough to change the gesture into mouse wheel events, you should be able to catch the events and inspect the [delta](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#delta) property. Is that what you're doing already? If you don't see any delta events, then it might be that the zoom is being performed at the container level (i.e. beyond your ability to control)?

Comment: Good point - I ran a quick test and indeed the zoom gesture in Win 7 is translated to wheel deltas in Flash.  Since that's the case I'm guess that I won't have much control over how many deltas are sent for a particular zoom.